# calculate discount for total amount multiplied by 100

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble calculating the discount of total order amount of products that is multiplied by 100.
In my database I'm saving the product price multiplied by 100 `e.g.: $price = 33.5 * 100` I'm doing this to prevent wrong calculation of the `decimal point .5` when retrieving the data and adding those to other products.

So I have this for now

```
$test_product_price = 10000 // actual price is 100 because it's save multiplied by 100
$quantity = 3;
$discount = 10.5%;

$order_amount = $test_product_price * 3 // will produce 30000 but actual price is 300 when divided by 100
```

Now what I want is deduct the `$discount` which is `10.5%`

for actual amount this is working fine

```
$discounted_amount = 300 - (300 * (10.5 / 100)); // will produce 268.5
```

but how can I do that on my end that is my amounts are multiplied by `100`

Comment: Can't you just divide the amounts on your end by `100` before applying the calculation you provided?

Comment: Usually dicsounts are presented as fraction, not percent. So it would be `0.105`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a bit long winded but accurate;

```
 <?php
 $amount = 100;
 $number = 3;
 $percent = 10.5;
 $subtotal = $amount * $number;
 $discount = ($percent / 100) * $subtotal;
 $total = $subtotal - $discount;
 $total = number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');
 echo $total;
 ?>
```

Comment: thank you SJacks, I don't know to them why they are like that, anyways they didn't deserve to be in the stackoverflow.